# R dplyr mutate: creating one variable from multiple column variables using "or" logic

Tags: r, dplyr, categorical-data

I am trying to do something that I think is straightforward but I am having an issue with.

I have several medication-related column variables (`med_1`, `med_2`, `med_3` for example). *These are character variables- so they have text for the name of medications*

I want to combine them all into variable `anymed` using or logic, so that I can then use `anymed` to look at any medications reported across all medication related fields.

I am trying the following, for dataset FinalData.

```
FinalData <- FinalData %>% mutate(anymed = med_1 | med_2 | med_3)
```

I am receiving this error:

```
*Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `anymed`.
ℹ `anymed = |...`.
x operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types*
```

Could someone help explain what code I should use instead since these are characters? Do I need to convert to factors?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. That includes a sample of data and the output you're trying to get

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `pivot_longer` from `tidyverse` to get them all in the same column. I also dropped the column name (i.e., `col`), but you could remove that line if you want to know what column the medication came from. I'm unsure what your data looks like, so I just made a small example to show how to do it.

```
library(tidyverse)

FinalData %>%
  pivot_longer(-ind, names_to = "col", values_to = "anymed") %>%
  select(-col)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
    ind anymed
  <dbl> <chr> 
1     1 meda  
2     1 meda  
3     1 meda  
4     2 medb  
5     2 medb  
6     2 medb
```

It's a little unclear what your expected output is. But if you are wanting to combine all medications in each row, then you can also use `unite`.

```
FinalData %>%
  unite("any_med", c("med_1", "med_2", "med_3"), sep = " | ")
```

Output

```
  ind            any_med
1   1 meda | meda | meda
2   2 medb | medb | medb
```

**Data**

```
FinalData <-
  structure(
    list(
      ind = c(1, 2),
      med_1 = c("meda", "medb"),
      med_2 = c("meda",
                "medb"),
      med_3 = c("meda", "medb")
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-2L)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this kind of solution:

```
# data:
df <- tibble(med_1 = "A", med_2 = "B", med_3 = "C")

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(any_med = paste(c(med_1, med_2, med_3), collapse = " | "))
```

```
  med_1 med_2 med_3 any_med  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    
1 A     B     C     A | B | C
```

Comment: I guess I was unclear if they wanted them all in the same column or wanted a `rowwise` solution.

Comment: I am not sure. We will see! :-)

Comment: Hi! Thank you. Med_1, Med_2, and Med_3 are columns, each with ~40 medications. Each row is a unique combination of patient+visit#. I think rowwise works but I am not sure about your first line of code (where med_1 = "A" for example), since med_1 = ~40 values. Would I need to write out all of them?

Comment: Do the following: type in your console: `dput(head(here the name of your dataframe))` then copy the output and add it to your question. Ideally you could construct a desired output. This is the way your chances to get what you desire increase rapidly!